# Excel conditional formatting based on absolute numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am unable to get Excel conditional formatting working based on a percentage from 0 to 100. It seems to format based on the minimum and maximum number in the selection.

I have 3 separate rules with the same settings. The middle row should be all red but instead the 15% is as green as an 80%.

Have tried changing the rule to use number but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 tips:

1. select all rows at once to apply formatting. It should like seen like [image: this image]. The range contains 1st, 4th and the 7th rows all together.
2. Use **Number** instead of **Percent** for *minimum* and *maximum* number. This will avoid minor updates on colors. Here is a sample: [image: rule screenshot]

Comment: tried that but doesn't seem to work, can you share your results?
https://imgur.com/a/Ie9IDg8

Comment: @Mik You set Maximum as 0 too. It should be 1 because you are dealing with percentage values.

Comment: ok was just following your screenshot which had 0 :) looks better now, it's just not intuitive

Comment: @Mik sorry for screenshot :) Also, please mark as solved, if it works for you.